# Почему std::invoke работает для данных в классе?

Tags: c++, классы, language-lawyer

Почему `std::invoke` работает ещё и для указателей на данные в классе, а не только для указаталей на функции-члены? Разве логически он не должен только какие-то функциональные объекты вызывать?

Это сказано в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), а ещё иллюстрируется примером:

```
#include <functional>

struct A {
    int x = 42;
    double y = 42.;
} a;

int main() {
    std::invoke(&A::x, a);            
    std::invoke(&A::y, a);                
}
```

Ожидаемое мной поведение в такой ситуации — ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Результат вызова в этом случае получается как если бы это был указатель на геттер.

Comment: @user7860670 да, но почему так сделано? Я же могу и нормальную геттер-функцию написать и дать указатель на неё, если надо

Comment: Может для упрощения, чтобы не приходилось писать этот геттер? Кроме того, указатель на нестатические поля класса в С++ по факту всегда является функций-гетерром

Comment: Потому что  и те и другие являются членами, с разницей,  что     одни являются еще и функциями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54381522/13970074) участника [@Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) для [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54374544/13970074).

---

При разработке стандартной библиотеки C++11 множество фич было взято из библиотек Boost. Для ответа на этот вопрос интересны следующие:

- `bind`
- `function`
- `reference_wrapper`
- `mem_fn`

Все они, в той или иной степени, относятся к какому-то вызываемому объекту, который может принимать некоторое количество параметров и возвращать определённое значение. Раз так, они пытаются обращаться с вызываемыми объектами единообразно. С++11, когда адаптировал эти фичи, ввёл концепцию `INVOKE` вместе с правилами идеальной передачи аргументов, для того чтобы они могли схожим образом работать с вызываемыми объектами.

Единственная цель `mem_fn` состоит в преобразовании указателя на член в объект, вызываемый с помощью `()`. Для указателей на функции-члены очевидным при таком вызове является вызов функции-члена, на который этот указатель указывает, передавая экземпляр класса и необходимые аргументы. Для указателей на переменные класса наиболее очевидным поведением является возвращение значения этой переменной в переданном экземпляре класса.

Возможность превращать указатель на переменную в классе в унарную функцию, которая возвращает значение этой переменной, достаточно полезна сама по себе. Вы можете использовать что-то вроде `std::transform`, передавая `mem_fn` для указателя на переменную-член, чтобы сгенерировать последовательность значений, которые обращаются к этой переменной. Ranges, добавленные в C++20, делают её ещё более полезной, так как вы можете создавать трансформированные ranges, манипулируя последовательностями объектов, используя только указатель на член.

Дело в том, что мы хотим, чтобы это работало независимо от типов этих объектов. Если объект оказался вызываемым, то `mem_fn` должен быть в состоянии обращаться к этому объекту, как и к любому другому объекту. Тот факт, что он оказался вызываемым, не имеет значения для цели `mem_fn`.

Но `boost::function` и `boost::bind` могут принимать указатели на члены. Поведение в случае такой передачи основано на `boost::mem_fn`. Поэтому, если `mem_fn` трактует указатели на переменные-члены как унарные функции, возвращающие значения этих переменных, то и `boost::function` с `boost::bind` должны трактовать их таким же образом.

Когда C++11 собрал всё это в одну обобщённую концепцию, такое поведение перешло в `INVOKE`.

Таким образом, с этимологической стороны, именно поэтому `INVOKE` работает так: потому что все указанные фичи должны обращаться с вызываемыми объектами одинаково и весь смысл `mem_fn` относительно указателей на переменные-члены состоит в обращении с ними как с унарными функциями, возвращающими значения этих переменных. Поэтому именно так все остальные должны обрабатывать эти указатели.

И разве это не хорошо? Разве это неверное поведение? Действительно бы вы хотели, чтобы указатели на члены класса вели себя совершенно по-разному в зависимости от того, указывают ли они на вызываемые объекты или нет? Это бы сделало невозможным написание обобщённого кода, который принимает такие указатели и производит операции над последовательностями объектов с помощью них. Как бы вы смогли обобщённо обращаться к указателям, не зная заранее, получите ли вы ссылку на объект или вызовете его?

Answer (score 1):

Ну а почему нет? Это удобно.

Вот пример:

```
struct A
{
    bool is_dead = false;
};

std::vector<A> vec = ...;
std::erase_if(vec, &A::is_dead);
```

Разве не удобно? Но этот код **не** компилируется, потому что `std::erase_if` (и вообще стандартные алгоритмы) не используют `std::invoke`.

Comment: Тогда `std::erase_if` должен различать передачу члена класса и standalone функции, чтобы понять, надо ли передавать объект класса в `std::invoke`. `std::erase_if` это же новая функция, т.е. при проектировании уже был доступен `std::invoke`, а значит могли его использовать, но не сделали этого

Comment: @dIm0n Не понял, зачем `erase_if` что-то различать? Он может всегда дергать `std::invoke(предикат, элемент);`. *"могли его использовать"* Возможно не стали для единообразия с существующими алгоритмами.

Comment: Ну да, если предикаты могут быть только членами элемента либо обычными функциями, то ок. Я имел в виду, что если мы захотим предикат из другого класса использовать, но может быть это не очень то и надо